# Add more references input reference in html

Tags: html

I would like to use one input field that is referenced by multiple forms on one page. or I would like to use `<input form="form1,form2,form3,form4" type="text" name="name" required  autocomplete="off"/><br>` or call the input field every time i submit each of the forms

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="5" align="center">Group Name: 
      <input form="form1,form2,form3,form4" type="text" name="name" required  autocomplete="off"/><br>
      </td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <form id="form1" action="plan.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="number" value="0"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="priceplan" value="25"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="10 PAX" style="width:100%; margin-top:0px;" class="button">
     </form>
    </td>
   <td>
    <form id="form2" action="plan.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="number" value="0"><br>
     <input type="hidden" name="priceplan" value="2"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="10 People" style="width:100%; margin-top:0px;" class="button">
    </form>
   </td>
   <td>
    <form id="form3" action="plan.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="number" value="0"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="priceplan" value="3"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="20 People" style="width:100%; margin-top:0px;" class="button">
   </form>
  </td>
  <td>
   <form id="form4" action="plan.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="0"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="priceplan" value="4"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="30 People" style="width:100%; margin-top:0px;" class="button">
   </form>
  </td>
  <td>
   <form id="form5" action="plan.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="0"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="priceplan" value="5"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="40 People" style="width:100%; margin-top:0px;" class="button">
  </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to use `<input form="form1,form2,form3,form4" type="text" name="name" required  autocomplete="off"/><br>` or call the input field every time i submit each of the forms

Comment: Please clarify your question; it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That is not possible in HTML5. Depending on why exactly you need this, your best options are probably to use JavaScript to either clone the field and insert a copy into each form, or create hidden fields in the form that are automatically populated with the content of the one "original", if the UI requires it to be in one place only or sth like that ...

Comment: I have multiple forms on a page but do not want to repeat the input field on each form, so i have decided to have it somewhere in my table every time I press the send button it also submits the value from the group name.

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Javacsript here is an example using jQuery:

- first you give ur unique input an ID (id="uniqueInput")
- then on the submit you append it to the form

> ```
> $('form').submit(function(e){
>   e.preventDefault();
>   $('<input>').attr({
>     type: 'hidden',
>     id: 'foo',
>     name: 'bar',
>     value: $('#uniqueInput').val()
>   }).appendTo($(this));
> })
> ```